# applescript and terminal ( run several do shell script in one terminal window )

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I do have several shell scripts whom are get activate not really behind each other.

But I want to stay in the same terminal window.

To simplify the problem, lets say that as example

first script. - cd to the working directory
second.       - do some things and get files from that directory
third.        - dome more thing on the newly files/folders in that directory.
fourth.       - ....

How can I let script 2 and 3 ( all the script thus ) run in that very same directory and window that is opened during script 1?

F.e how can I avoid using the full path to that folder for every file.

EDIT: After adayzdone's answer I realize that I forgot to mention that I need also administrator privileges for one of the scripts

EDIT2: For now I use this

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set newTab to do script
    set current settings of newTab to settings set "Grass"
    do script "bin/sh/ echo 'xx' | su;" in newTab
    do script "cd " & quoted form of realParentPath in newTab
    do script shellscript1 in newTab
    do script shellscript..n in newTab
    activate
end tell
```

but still no dice with the privileges.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd ~/" in window 1
    do script "ls -a" in window 1
end tell
```

OR

```
property usr : "username"
property pswd : "password"

set xxx to do shell script "cd ~/ ; ls -a " user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Thank you, did help already. However, I need also administrator privileges for one of the scripts. But I can't find/don't know a way how to add privileges or should I use "echo $passw | sudo -u root" in my shell script

Comment: Is there a reason you need to run it from Terminal and not with do shell script?

Comment: With do shell script I have no common shell, f.e Cd in the first do shell script isn't of any use in the 2'nd do shell script. Am I right or... Second reason, I like to see also visual some results of the script without logging per se. But Anyway, if You can tell me how I can solve the CD issue, I can use that in an other script. Thanks again. BTW, with the privileges issue, I see I lost a line in my comment that I always get the 'sorry' as result.

Comment: Thank you. Yes but thats with "do shell script" and not with "do script", and will loose the CD path.

Comment: as long as you separate the commands with a ; as I did in my answer, you will not loose the CD path.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I know, but I have to do things in Apple script between the shell scripts. Thats the reason why there are 3+ shell scripts. If it was possible to do it that way ( in one go ), I will use an external shell.command script.