# AppleScript access not allowed when trying to run shell script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, applescript

New to AppleScript but I'm trying to migrate over from terminal scripting.  After much research I am having issues trying to get a shell script running from within the .app file.

What I have so far:

```
to the_foo()
    tell application "Finder"
        set current_path to container of (path to me) as alias
        set path_in_posix to POSIX path of current_path
    end tell

    tell application "Terminal"
        set new_terminal to do script " "
        activate
        do script "cd " & path_in_posix in window 1
        do shell script "ls " & POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Scripts/foobar.sh" in window 1
    end tell
end the_foo
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Learned to open a new terminal with: [Applescript to open a NEW terminal window in current space](https://superuser.com/questions/195633/applescript-to-open-a-new-terminal-window-in-current-space)

I added `in window 1` when I learned that `do script` opens a new terminal window every time, referenced: [applescript and terminal ( run several do shell script in one terminal window )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090235/applescript-and-terminal-run-several-do-shell-script-in-one-terminal-window)

I originally tried:

```
set script_Location to path to resource "Contents:Resources:Scripts:"
set run_Script to (quoted form of script_Location) & "foobar.sh"
do shell script run_Script
```

after referencing: [How to change AppleScript path to a Terminal-style path?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200125/how-to-create-an-osx-application-to-wrap-a-call-to-a-shell-script) but when I run it I get the same error.

So how can I run the shell script located within the `Scripts` folder within the same `window 1`?  I would ideally like to set a variable for the path so I can put multiple shells scripts in the `Scripts` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a typo

```
 do script "ls " & POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Scripts/foobar.sh" in window 1
```

rather than

```
 do shell script "ls " & ...
```

I recommend to use `System Events` instead of the `Finder` to get the container of the script

```
tell application "System Events"
    set path_in_posix to POSIX path of container of (path to me)
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Vadian had the correct and better approach in a one liner.  I did change

```
"Contents/Resources/Scripts/foobar.sh"
```

to

```
set script_Location to "Contents/Resources/Scripts/"
set foobar to do script "bash " & POSIX path of (path to me) & script_Location & "foobar.sh" in window 1
```

this approach helps if I want to add more than one shell script in the `Scripts` folder.